# 'Find' spelling mistakes in TeXworks

Tags: texworks, spelling, dictionaries

I'm reasonably happy with the dictionary functionality in TeXworks but I am struggling to see how I can 'find' all the spelling mistakes in my (painfully long) tex file. I was hoping for a Wordesque spell checker in which I can scroll through each of my errors and accept or ignore the suggested changes.

I could install another editor that has this functionality but would prefer not to do this if possible.

Comment: Old, related feature request: https://code.google.com/p/texworks/issues/detail?id=227

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, seeing as there is not a native TexWorks solution, I thought I would post my solution to the problem. Instead of using another editor, I've decided upon Aspell (http://aspell.net/). It's a great little spell checking tool. It's primarily linux based, although they do have a Windows port.

I run it from the command line on my .tex files and it scrolls through each error in turn, presenting me with a list of valid alternatives. My thesis has a number of scientific terms in it, which are obviously not recognised. You can create your own additional list of valid words or, as I've done, just 'add' the words as you go.