# Jumping between spelling mistakes

Tags: texworks, spelling

I am looking for a way to jump between misspelled words in TeXworks: in a large document it becomes difficult to keep track of spelling mistakes, specially if many of these are not actually spelling mistakes (scientific terms, words in languages other than the main one, or even uncommon enough words).

Is there a way to do this in TeXworks itself? I am aware of [this old question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155640/find-spelling-mistakes-in-texworks) asking more or less the same thing, but I was hoping that, 8 years later, an easier solution might be available...

Answer (score 0):

This is not really answering your question, but might be helpful anyway.

I use [overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/) which is web based, then you can use the plugin by choice to do the spelling.